# Deploying Pyramid to dotcloud

Tags: python, pyramid, wsgi, dotcloud

What is the proper way to deploy a Pyramid project to dotcloud?

The contents of wsgi.py:

```
import os, sys
from paste.deploy import loadapp
current_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
application = loadapp('config:production.ini', relative_to=current_dir)
```

I'm currently getting the following error.

```
uWSGI Error
wsgi application not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get pass the uWSGI Error error using :

```
import os
from paste.deploy import loadapp
current_dir = os.getcwd()
application = loadapp('config:production.ini', relative_to=current_dir)
```

I still had a path problem with the static files so I changed:

```
config.add_static_view('static', 'static', cache_max_age=3600)
```

to

```
config.add_static_view('<myapp>/static', 'static', cache_max_age=3600)
```

Answer (score 2):

This could indicate that `wsgi.py` could not be imported successfully.

You can check the following:

- output of `dotcloud logs appname.servicename`
- log into the service with `dotcloud ssh appname.servicename`, then go to the `current` directory, start `python` and see what happens if you try to do `from wsgi import application`

If that can help, here is a super-simple Pyramid app:
https://github.com/jpetazzo/pyramid-on-dotcloud

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'hellodjango.settings'
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

http://docs.dotcloud.com/tutorials/python/django/

Comment: ooops. i think this is not the answer you were looking for. sorry. i wasn't paying attention. cheers!